# Disable quote replacement in sgml-mode

Tags: html, quote

In sgml-mode, when I type quotes `"`, they are automatically replaced by `&#34;`. The culprit is the function `sgml-name-self`. Perhaps it is called automatically on characters in the variable `sgml-specials` (?); however, when I set `sgml-specials` to `nil`, the issue persists.

How to turn this automatic replacement off? Any help would be greatly appreciated, *this automatic replacement drives me insane*.

Comment: Setting `sgml-specials` to `nil` will do it, but you need to do it before `sgml-mode` is loaded

Comment: Yay, thank you! This works. Indeed, in my case it was set on `after-load`, and I replaced it with `(setq sgml-specials nil)` in my `.init.el` and it works. Please copy your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sgml-mode` will not set up the key bindings to insert replacements for `'` and `"` if you set `sgml-specials` to `nil`, as long as do that before `sgml-mode` is loaded.